# Strange error in DataSet property

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, dataset, nullreferenceexception

I have several projects in 3 layers structure :

- Business layer
- Data access layer
- Model layer

Now in the Model layer, which I store all of my DataSets, there is one strange error.

The error occured in the Business layer, which is : Failed to Enable constraints due to NULL values ... This happens because one or more  columns in the table contain NULL value but this is not possible because I've set the property : NullValue = (empty for string & 0 for decimal) for all the columns of all the tables in my datasets.

After a while trying to solve the problem by checking again and again all the datatables's columns in the datasets, and by cleaning the whole solution and rebuilding, I got no luck.

But in the end, I solved the problem following these steps : 
- Clean the Model project
- Open the dataset (the one I know that caused the error) 
- Save it (with out any modification) 
- Rebuild the project
- Rebuild the business layer project

And voila, the error's gone!

Now even the issue's solved, I'm asked to provide explanation which I don't possess. So if anyone there have a clue, please, help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you always generating DataSet from .XSD? Or sometimes you modify your DataSet manually!

Comment: @Sudipta Aiti I only use the designer to modify them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DataSet should be generated always from .xsd through Visual Studio Custom Tool MSDataSetGenerator. Looks like something was changed manually in your DataSet which caused problem. Once you redo everything DataSet generated from .xsd once again through MSDataSetGenerator and started working.

It can't be considered as root cause analysis, this is just a probability!

Comment: This is a correct answer. I checked after reading yours and found out a member of my team replaced the designer.vb file accidentally